# Is there a dua to protect me from the humiliation of revealing my academic performance from my relatives?

Tags: dua, family

I am a person who concealed my academic performance from my relatives, except my parents. I recently disclosed the truth to my parents. Now I am afraid of humiliation when relatives hear my results. You may feel that these are silly issues when compared to other peoples complex problems in their life, but this is something which causes me mental anguish and lack of concentration. I would like to know whether there is any dua to be protected from this situation.

Comment: Does taqiya count?

Answer (score 1):

> O Allah! I ask Thee for forgiveness and security in my religion and my worldly affairs, in my family and my property; O Allah! conceal my faults , and keep me safe from the things which I fear; O Allah! guard me in front of me and behind me, on my right hand and on my left, and from above me: and I seek in Thy greatness from receiving unexpected harm from below me.

[Sunan Abi Dawud 5074](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/43/302)

Comment: No matter how many times it's mentioned to add a useful comment, rather than mute downvote, but it still happens.

Comment: Sorry, I did not get it, what is a "link only answer"?

Comment: A commentless answer with only a link to an evidence. But in this case this is ok as OP asked only for an dua'.